# Angular 6 library lint and build errors using Injector.get

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-cli

I have an Angular library which is consumed by a number of other projects. I'm currently updating it to Angular 6.

In the lib are some places where I need to get an injectable class, but I cannot use normal constructor DI, e.g. in a custom decorator. For this I have a custom resolver that uses the `Injector.get` method to get a reference to the injectable class. The resolver looks like this:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CoreModuleInjector {
  public static injector: Injector;

  constructor(public injector: Injector) {
    CoreModuleInjector.injector = injector;
  }

  public static get(token: any): any {
    if (CoreModuleInjector.injector) {
      return CoreModuleInjector.injector.get(token);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And then in other places, I am using it like this:

```
const state: any = CoreModuleInjector.get(ActivatedRoute);
```

This works in the apps that use the lib, but I see a lint warning for the custom resolver that says:

> get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type or InjectionToken

And, I cannot do a prod build, when I try, I see this error:

> Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler.

The error points to the line `return CoreModuleInjector.injector.get(token);` in the custom resolver. I have tried changing this line to this:

```
return CoreModuleInjector.injector.get<any>(token as any);
```

And that does remove the lint error, but it doesn't fix the build error.

I'd like to either fix the build issue so I can continue using the injector in the same way, or alternatively, I need a better way to get injectable classes in places where normal DI can't be used